# Laptop keyboard stops working when external keyboard disconnected

Tags: usb, keyboard

I have an annoying problem every time I need to move with my laptop to another room. After disconnecting all external devices and few minutes work with laptop keyboard always facing problem with huge lag/typing. A few seconds later the keyboard goes crazy and repeats keys I've pressed, infinitely. Restarting or connecting external keyboard works around the issue.

I was trying many things to fight it back:

- Adding `psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0 i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` `/etc/default/grub`
- turn off some options in access improvements menu
- some BIOS options
- reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-all`

No luck. I had it on Ubuntu 18.04 and have it on 19.10.

Laptop: Thinkpad E540

Comment: What laptop vendor and model is it? You should know, that I also use laptop and have no problems with keyboard. Do you understand, that it could be hardware specific issue. So your hardware info is required in this case.

Comment: This is Thinkpad E540 and hardware problem is rather unlikely because I had windows on it few months ago and there wasn't a such problem

Comment: Hardware problem in meaning of there could be a problem with drivers for your hardware. Sorry for that.

Comment: Have the same issue with Lenovo ThinkPad E470 and Ubuntu 19.10. I know for sure that this issue started to appear relatively recently. Initially, 18.04 was installed, and everything was okay. But now I have the same laptop's keyboard issues after disconnecting the USB external keyboard. Would like to know the answer.